# @RequestParam spring MVC , make one of two request params mandatory

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, controller, request

I am writing a service wherein I take in either an id or a location and I want to enforce the constraint that either the id or the location must be specified in my @Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/loc.json",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String localiaztionRequest(@RequestParam(value = "location",  required = false) String callback
            ,@RequestParam(value = "id",  required = false) String uuid
            ,@RequestParam(value = "callback",  required = false) String callback) {
        //model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

        return "hello";
    }
```

For clarity, I want each request to send either the location parameter or the id parameter. How do I enforce such a constraint on a pair of input parameters? Also as an aside could someone please explain to me the use of ModelMap , what is the effect of model.addAttribute("message","Hello World!") ? 
Sorry if the questions seem rather naive, I'm extremely new to the spring framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should split it into two different controller methods

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loc.json",method = RequestMethod.GET, params={"location"})
public @ResponseBody String localizationRequestByLoc(@RequestParam String location, @RequestParam String callback) {
    //model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/loc.json",method = RequestMethod.GET, params={"id"})
public @ResponseBody String localizationRequestById(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String callback) {
    //model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: The answer is right and it is working ,but NOTE that the second @RequestParam isn't necessary , in this case the callback.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this (although indirect) would be to create a new object model representing the data to be passed in and another representing the data type and requiring both elements.

```
public enum MethodType
{
   First,
   Second
}

public class Filter
{
   [Required]
   public MethodType {get;set;} 
   [Required]
   public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

use this object for the action method and view
and let the action method in the controller convert the object

Comment: The question was mention with Java.